# Display zero values in Group option

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a problem in Excel 2013 Grouping option. I have created dates and number of tickets created for over a period of time (3 years). I group data on `Days` to get weekly report. Upon grouping, I see that for some week there is no data. So I want it to appear as "Zero" for that week. But what I see is that week does not appear in the grouped data list.

This is what I am trying to explain - I have selected May 2014 as Created Month and I have daily data hence have grouped it as Days. But you can see that `5/12/2014 - 5/18/2014` and `5/19/2014 - 5/25/2014` is missing. I know they have no value but I want it to appear as zero so that my graph appears correct.

```
4/28/2014 - 5/4/2014           4
5/5/2014 - 5/11/2014           9
5/26/2014 - 6/1/2014           1
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this (other than somehow adding records for the zeros)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no gaps in your date ranges.